# How to change the cursor keys in VIM

Tags: vim, keymapping

I'm trying to change the cursor keys in VIM from the normal h,j,k,l to the home position for typing j,k,l,;.  Any suggestions on how to do that?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that if you do this, you'll clobber a pretty useful key: `;`

Comment: My advice. Dont. This might sound rude but lots and lots of people use `hjkl` to their advantage. I agree that sometimes its desirable to stay away from the mob-mentality, question something this basic would be considered n00bish.

Answer (score 6):

`:help map.txt` will give you a lots of information on the subject.

You can try the following to achieve your goal:

```
nnoremap j h
nnoremap k j
nnoremap l k
nnoremap ; l

vnoremap j h
vnoremap k j
vnoremap l k
vnoremap ; l
```